# How do I force Adobe Acrobat DC to tile output in landscape?

Tags: acrobat

I have Acrobat Reader DC (19.008.20081), with a large image (9000 across x 12300 high pixels). I am using the tiling features of Reader DC to print to jpg images, printer being ImagePrinter Pro print-to-image utility.

I want the tiles printed landscape to fit A4, but despite setting landscape everywhere there is such an option(Properties, Page Setup, also in Control Panel), it keeps trying to tile portrait. How do I force it to print landscape to images?